# Influence of fast position change when using WLAN or e.g. 2.4GHz

Tags: signal-processing, communication, wifi

I tried to find some information about the following problem statement:
E.g. when having a rotating spindle (e.g. 20000RPMs) or having a RC car, which is moving really fast, will e.g. WLAN 2.4Ghz work reliable?

I mean, assuming that the signal strength is sufficient, will I get problem due to the relative velocity or can I neglect that?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question - never seen any specs for this but in case it is enough for your needs this link claims that a wifi drone can do 11mph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_AR.Drone

Answer (score 1):

You should find some discussion of this in the 802.11p amendment -wireless access in vehicular environments (WAVE) - which is part of the 802.11-2012 standard.

802.1p specifically addresses WiFi in vehicles at up to 200km/h so I expect would have some discussion of the issues of a fast moving station.